# apollo-server-express, graphql custom schema directive

Tags: express, graphql, apollo-server

This is weird for me.
According [this](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-directives/) document i made my Auth SchemaDirective like this:

```
class RequireAuthDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
  visitFieldDefinition(field) {
    const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = field;
    field.resolve = async (...args) => {
      let [, params, { req, res, connection }] = args;
      let { user } = req || connection.context;
      if (!!user) {
        return await resolve.apply(this, args);
      } else {
        throw new AuthenticationError('You must be signed in to view this resource.');
      }
    };
  }
}
```

This works fine in every `Query`, `Mutation`, `Subscription`

But when i use an external async method to check authorization like this:

```
class RequireAuthDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
  visitFieldDefinition(field) {
    const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = field;
    field.resolve = async (...args) => {
      let [, params, { req, res, connection }] = args;
      let { user } = req || connection.context;
      if (!!user) {
        if (await isAllowed(user.id, field.name, params)) return await resolve.apply(this, args); // ChkPoint
        throw new AuthenticationError('You are not authorized to access this resource.'); 
      } else {
        throw new AuthenticationError('You must be signed in to access this resource.');
      }
    };
  }
}
```

This works fine in `Queries` and `Mutations` but not in subscriptions!

Note: if i remove the `ChkPoint` condition ( Which is returning true ) it will works in subscription.